# I dont know how put admob in my android game

Tags: java, android, layout, admob

**Hello, i have a mainView.**

**my MainActivity.java**

```
package net.canarolab.puzzleroad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private AdView adView;
    private MainView mainView;
    private final int MENU_SELECT_RESET = 1, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT = 2;

    // MUSICA
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;// para musica de fondo (se declara aqui para que
                            // pueda

    // utilizarla todos nuestros metodos)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // MUSIC
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.merry);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Apago la barra de título
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Apago la barra de estado
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Activity Quiero solo tapa
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        // View Establezca el
        mainView = new MainView(this);
        setContentView(mainView);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        // Create the adView
        // Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2f8fe3af5a6");

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        request.setTesting(true);

        adView.loadAd(request);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_RESET, 0, "Reset");
        menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT, 0, "Contact");
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Leí el recuento juego
        this.mainView.gameCount.read();
        Log.d("", "read");
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();

        // Escribo el recuento de juego.
        this.mainView.gameCount.save();
        Log.d("", "save");

        super.onPause();
        // No voy a desaparecer en esta actitud no hay más.
        // finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

        super.onDestroy();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_SELECT_RESET:
            this.mainView.gameCount.reset();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Has been reset．", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case MENU_SELECT_CONTACT:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "idea");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text of email");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[] { " trabajonacho33@gmail.com" });
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**this is my activity_main.xml**
if you want you can tell me another case than i can mix canvas with a layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

my problem is setContentView
and only can see the admob no my game
thank you

Comment: Why don't you use XML and AndroidManifest to add the AdMob? It's easier that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set ContextView twice. Don't.
The last one will replace the previous so MainView is never going to be injected.

Ie Loe one of the 2 setContentView calls below

```
// View Establezca el
mainView = new MainView(this);
setContentView(mainView);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

And consider defining the AdView in XML.

Comment: RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
  mainView = new MainView(this);

Comment: Hello William is good idea but dont work, if you want i can send you my proyect but i dont see your email.

Comment: See my updated answer. If this doesn't solve your problem update your question with your revised code.